# embedForm extra Field hidden

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

part of my code in listForm.class.php:

```
public function configure() {
    $list_id = $this->getOption('list_id');
    $endkunde_id = $this->getOption('endkunde_id');
    $shopname_id = 1;


    $todoWrapperForm = new sfForm();
    $todoWrapperForm = new sfForm();
    //$todos = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Todo')->findAll();


    //$todos = Doctrine_Core::getTable('EinkaufslisteElemente')->findAll();
    $todos = Doctrine_Core::getTable('EinkaufslisteElemente')
            ->createQuery('ee')
            ->where('ee.einkaufsliste_id = ?', $list_id)
            ->innerJoin('ee.Einkaufsliste e')

            ->andWhere('e.shopname_id = ?', $shopname_id)
           ->innerJoin('e.EinkaufslisteEndkunde ek')
            ->execute();


    foreach ($todos as $todo) {
        $todoWrapperForm->embedForm($todo->getId(), new EinkaufslisteElementeForm($todo));
    }
    $todoWrapperForm->embedForm('new_1', new EinkaufslisteElementeForm());  // add one blank todo to start
    $this->embedForm('todos', $todoWrapperForm);


        $this->list =  new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('rows' => '10', 'cols' => '35'));

    $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model'=>'todo', 'column'=>'task'), array('required' => false)))               ;
    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('todo_list[%s]');
}
```

I want to create an extra field from 'Customer' with his name which is not hidden, and I want to create an input field hidden with the list_id from the table 'List'. How can I do it with embedForm?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in your `embedForm`? Since it's related to the listForm, put it inside.

Comment: then how can i put it inside?

Comment: using sfWidgetFormInputHidden ?

Comment: I just can't set another Widget.

Comment: Here we go! Do I need more than this validator?

Comment: I would like to know if you want to add these two fields into the `todoWrapperForm` or into each `EinkaufslisteElementeForm` ?

Comment: Oh no, I didn't get your question immediatly. No, I don't want them in embedForm!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `listForm`, just add at the bottom of your configure:

```
$this->widgetSchema['list_id']    = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
// do not forget to add the propel validator (ie: the one that can check if `list_id` is ok - like in the database)
$this->validatorSchema['list_id'] = new sfValidatorPass();
```

Then, in your action, don't forget to set a default to `list_id`:

```
$form = new listForm();
$form->setDefault('list_id', $list_id);
```

Comment: I didn't think about to create a new form! Actually pretty simple! The beauty of symfony. Thanks!